# Open a text file in C#

Tags: c#, file

I'm writing a Windows-Forms Application in which I log some Data while the program is running and I write it in a temporary file with this code:

```
string path = Path.GetTempFileName();
byte[] text = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Some Text");
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    fs.Write(text, 0, text.Length);
}
```

After the programm passed through I want to show/open the file in the Microsoft Editor. How can I do it. I googled around but I didn't find anything, maybe i searched with the wrong words.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: MIcrosoft Editor? Just save the text file as .txt format and open the file using c# and Windows wil automatically choose the program associated with it and open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Process.Start("Yourfile.txt")
```